# Mongodb subdocument search and select

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have mongo database with this structure:

[Collection structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np0ai.png)

I need to get parent document and its subdocuments between time range.
I'm using nodejs mongoosejs driver. Here's my current request:

```
    var searchQueryTerminal = TickModel
    .findOne({
        symbol:symbol,
        'tickData.timestamp':{
            $gte:dateStart,
            $lte:dateEnd
        },
        broker:{$in: broker},
        MTVersion:MTVersion
    });
```

I have 1 parent document in result, as expected, but it contains all subdocuments, not only in time range. How can I do it in correct way with mongoose driver? I don't really want to do it on node-side, cuz amount of subdocuments can be several millions.

Schemas:

```
var TickDataSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
bid: Number,
ask: Number,
timestamp: {
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now,
    expires: '7d'
}});


var TickSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
    broker:{
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    account: Number,
    symbol: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    MTVersion:Number,
    key: {
    type:String,
        index:true
    },
    tickData:[TickDataSchema]
});
```

Comment: p.s. Sorry for inserting link instead of image. Low rep.

Comment: @chridam, here you go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2897) from vkarpov15

This is because mongoose's .elemMatch() function is a helper for MongoDB's $elemMatch query operator rather than the $elemMatch projection operator. See the mongoose docs on elemMatch. Admittedly the distinction between the two is tricky.

You can either use the explicit form I gave you or the .select() helper:

```
TickModel.
  findOne({
    "symbol": 'EURUSD',
    "tickData.timestamp": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2015-04-17T10:06:00.000Z"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2015-04-17T10:10:00.000Z")
    },    
    "MTVersion": 4
  }).
  select(
    "tickData": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "timestamp": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2015-04-17T10:06:00.000Z"),
                "$lte": ISODate("2015-04-17T10:10:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    }
  }).exec(callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Mongoose **[implementation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch)** of [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/). Tested with the following collection in mongo:

```
db.test.insert([
    { "symbol": "AMBC", "MTVersion": 0.25, "tickData": [{ "bid": 1, "ask": 1.5, "timestamp": ISODate("2015-01-28T08:00:00.000Z") }, { "bid": 1, "ask": 1.3, "timestamp": ISODate("2015-01-21T08:00:00.000Z") }] },
    { "symbol": "MSFT", "MTVersion": 0.25, "tickData": [{ "bid": 1, "ask": 1.5, "timestamp": ISODate("2015-02-04T08:00:00.000Z") }, { "bid": 1, "ask": 1.3, timestamp: ISODate("2015-02-11T08:00:00.000Z") }] }
]);

var symbol = "AMBC",
    dateStart = new Date (2015, 0, 20),
    dateEnd = new Date(2015, 0, 22),
    MTVersion = 0.25;

db.test.findOne({
    "symbol": symbol,
    "tickData.timestamp": {
        "$gte": dateStart,
        "$lte": dateEnd
    },    
    "MTVersion": MTVersion
}, {
    "symbol": 1,
    "MTVersion": 1,
    "tickData": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "timestamp": {
                "$gte": dateStart,
                "$lte": dateEnd
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Returns**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5530f8c4180e849972938fdf"),
    "symbol" : "AMBC",
    "MTVersion" : 0.25,
    "tickData" : [ 
        {
            "bid" : 1,
            "ask" : 1.3,
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-01-21T08:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

So in Mongoose, you could do something like:

```
TickModel
    .findOne({
        symbol: symbol,
        broker: {$in: broker},
        MTVersion: MTVersion
    })
    .elemMatch("tickData", { "timestamp": {"$gte": dateStart, "$lte": dateEnd } })
    // .select({"tickData": { "$elemMatch": { "timestamp": {"$gte": dateStart, "$lte": dateEnd } }, "symbol": 1, "MTVersion": 1, "broker": 1 })
    .exec(cb);
```

Using aggregation framework, this can be achieved by the following pipeline:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "symbol": symbol,
            "tickData.timestamp": {
                "$gte": dateStart,
                "$lte": dateEnd
            },    
            "MTVersion": MTVersion
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$tickData"
    },
    {
        "$match": {            
            "tickData.timestamp": {
                "$gte": dateStart,
                "$lte": dateEnd
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            _id: {
                "id": "$_id",
                "broker": "$broker",
                "account": "$account"
                "symbol": "$symbol",
                "MTVersion": "$MTVersion",
                "key": "$key"
            },
            "tickData": {
                "$addToSet": "$tickData"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "tickData": 1,
            "broker": "$_id.broker",
            "account": "$_id.account"
            "symbol": "$_id.symbol",
            "MTVersion": "$_id.MTVersion",
            "key": "$_id.key"
        }
    }
];
TickModel.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Result: (using the above sample documents)

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "tickData" : [ 
                {
                    "bid" : 1,
                    "ask" : 1.3,
                    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-01-21T08:00:00.000Z")
                }
            ],
            "symbol" : "AMBC",
            "MTVersion" : 0.25
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's much better, but result of your example find/findOne returns document with only first subdocument. And it works only from shell. Mongoose results are the same.

Comment: @BadVolt Can you try the commented out part and see how that goes? I can't test the query as I don't have my server set up, at least you got the general idea. You can use `.select(..)` to project the fields that you want, including the matched subdocument. Let me know how that goes so that I can update my answer and if that meets your needs then accept, no obligations though :-)

Comment: .select doesn't work for sure. Even if I select 2023 year it still return one document with full subdoc collection. I'l continue researching elemMatch.

Comment: elemMatch didn't helped too. Found advice to use aggregate, will try.

Comment: thank you you all you help, but it didn't helped too. I have nothing returned.

Comment: Here's dump from collection. Mb it can make things more clear. [Pastebin DB dump](http://pastebin.com/MFgGqM9x)

Comment: @BadVolt Thanks for the update. What are the exact **`dateStart`** and **`dateEnd`** values you are using for your date range query to match the `tickData` array?

Comment: I'm using this.

    var dateStart=new Date('2015-04-17T10:06:00.000Z').toISOString();
    var dateEnd=new Date('2015-04-17T10:10:00.000Z').toISOString();

It shows result from shell, but gives nothing from mongoose. I have two profiler results here. [compare queries](http://pastebin.com/8RaTb3Rq)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the populate function

```
 var searchQueryTerminal = TickModel
    .findOne({
        symbol:symbol,
        broker:{$in: broker},
        MTVersion:MTVersion
    }).populate({
        path: 'tickData',
        match: { timestamp: { $gte:dateStart, $lte:dateEnd}},
    })
```

Comment: Didn't worked. It still shows document and all it's subdocuments. No subdocuments filtering.

Comment: Can we see more data? Maybe more than one fall in the time range